# How to get the records from db?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I worked in travel CRS protal. for hotel booking i want to block hotel 
depends on the cutoff dates.

```
 SELECT * FROM (`crs_service_supplier_details` as crs) JOIN `crs_service_room_type_detail` as Room ON `crs`.`service_apartment_id`=`Room`.`service_id` JOIN `crs_room_type` as crt ON `Room`.`room_type_id`=`crt`.`room_type_id` JOIN `crs_service_off_dates` as ccod ON `crs`.`service_apartment_id`=`ccod`.`co_service` WHERE `crs`.`city` like '%Chennai%' AND ('2016-10-27' NOT between ccod.cut_off_from AND ccod.cut_off_from) AND ('2016-10-28' NOT between ccod.cut_off_to AND ccod.cut_off_to) AND `Room`.`edate` > '2016-10-27' GROUP BY `crs`.`service_apartment_id`
```

this is the query but the problem was in cut had two days

```
co_id   co_service  cut_off_from    cut_off_to  cut_off_release_days cut_off
1       1       2016-10-20      2016-10-22          0               2016-10-20
2       1       2016-10-27      2016-10-28          0               2016-10-28
```

if i searched between `2016-10-20` and `2016-10-22` it get the "`2016-10-27 and 2016-10-28`" and show the result.

if i searched between `2016-10-27` and `2016-10-28` it get the "`2016-10-20 and 2016-10-22`" and show the result. 
it wont block any where of the system. please give some idea to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

May be your query is not right. May be this will help, just change in BETWEEN logic:

```
AND ('2016-10-27' NOT BETWEEN ccod.cut_off_from AND ccod.cut_off_to)
AND ('2016-10-28' NOT BETWEEN ccod.cut_off_to AND ccod.cut_off_from)
```

use the above.

The original code with BETWEEN doesn`t make sense:

```
AND ('2016-10-27' NOT BETWEEN ccod.cut_off_from AND ccod.cut_off_from)
AND ('2016-10-28' NOT BETWEEN ccod.cut_off_to AND ccod.cut_off_to)
```

Because it is making between on the same column.

Comment: what were you writing here? "this doesn`t make sense." Or "Does this make sense".. ?? ;)